# 403 errors when attempting to load stylesheets in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm attempting to convert a static website into a Zen subtheme and I keep getting 403's on all of the stylesheets my subtheme references. I tried changing permissions, but am still unable to load the files.

I thought the problem might be due to a messed up .htaccess file upon further inspection, I was unable to find a single htaccess file in the template tree.

Comment: check the permissions on the `.htaccess` file

Comment: it was actually missing so I created one but the errors still occur. I navigated up the site structure to see if there was another one but there is not.